# C++ algoritmos de distancia con Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Hola tengo este código en c++.

Su única entrada es una imagen totalmente blanca con un punto negro de un pixel en el ~centro (300x300), la img es de 600x600.png ubicada en una carpeta img/

El problema es que trato de realizar el CDA 3x3 http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~manzaner/Download/IAD/Grevera_04.pdf
basado en el primer pseudocodigo, pero el resultado es más apegado al chessboard, a pesar de tener y modificar con las variables d1 y d2, con valores 3 y 4 respectivamente.

En chessboard es de d1=1 y d2=1, si bien se muestra un recuadro blanco en el centro, en una imagen 100x100 puede ser mejor apreciado un cambio mínimo entre ambos conjuntos de valores modificados (d1, d2). Nota si me apego totalmente al pseudocodigo tengo errores de acceso de memoria no accesible o sin referencia es por eso que no se inicia desde 1 hasta i menor a Y, etc. en los 'for'.

Tengo la teoría de que es el tipo de dato uchar que no me permite hacer ciertas comparaciones, he intentado con Vec3i, int, char, Vec3b eh echo tantos intentos pero los resultados varian hasta mostrar imágenes surrealistas, este código es el que me ha dado “mejores” resultados.

De antemano, ¡Gracias!.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

Mat I = imread("img/6x6.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if(I.empty()){return -1;}int X = I.rows;int Y = I.cols;

///Chamfer 3x3//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
uchar d1=3; uchar d2=4;
Mat d(X, Y, CV_8UC1);//Mat m(rows, cols)
for(int i = 1; i < Y-1; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < X-1; j++){
        d.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
    }
}
for(int i = 1; i < Y-1; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < X-1; j++){
        if(I.at<uchar>(i-1,j) != I.at<uchar>(i,j) || I.at<uchar>(i+1,j) != I.at<uchar>(i,j)||
           I.at<uchar>(i,j-1) != I.at<uchar>(i,j) || I.at<uchar>(i,j+1) != I.at<uchar>(i,j)){
            d.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 1; i < Y-1; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < X-1; j++){
            if(d.at<uchar>(i-1,j-1)+d2<d.at<uchar>(i, j)){d.at<uchar>(i, j) = d.at<uchar>(i-1, j-1)+d2;}
            if(d.at<uchar>(i,j-1)+d1<d.at<uchar>(i, j)){d.at<uchar>(i, j) = d.at<uchar>(i, j-1)+d1;}
            if(d.at<uchar>(i+1, j-1)+d2<d.at<uchar>(i, j)){d.at<uchar>(i, j) = d.at<uchar>(i+1, j-1)+d2;}
            if(d.at<uchar>(i-1, j)+d1<d.at<uchar>(i, j)){d.at<uchar>(i, j) = d.at<uchar>(i-1, j)+d1;}
    }
}
for(int i = Y-1; i > 1; i--){
    for(int j = X-1; j > 1; j--){
        if(d.at<uchar>(i+1, j)+d1<d.at<uchar>(i, j)){d.at<uchar>(i, j) = d.at<uchar>(i+1, j)+d1;}
        if(d.at<uchar>(i-1, j+1)+d2<d.at<uchar>(i, j)){d.at<uchar>(i, j) = d.at<uchar>(i-1, j+1)+d2;}
        if(d.at<uchar>(i, j+1)+d1<d.at<uchar>(i, j)){d.at<uchar>(i, j) = d.at<uchar>(i, j+1)+d1;}
        if(d.at<uchar>(i+1, j+1)+d2<d.at<uchar>(i, j)){d.at<uchar>(i, j) = d.at<uchar>(i+1, j+1)+d2;}
    }
}
for(int i = Y-1; i > 1; i--){
    for(int j = X-1; j > 1; j--){
        if(I.at<uchar>(i,j)==0){d.at<uchar>(i, j)=-d.at<uchar>(i, j);}
    }
}
///Chamfer 3x3//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

imshow("Input", I);
imshow("3x3", d);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No me puse analizar el problema en su totalidad, pero esta al revez X e Y.

```
for(int y = 1; y < Y-1; y++){
    for(int x = 1; x < X-1; x++){
        d.at<uchar>(x, y) = 255;
    }
}

for(int y = 1; y < Y-1; y++){
    for(int x = 1; x < X-1; x++){
        if(I.at<uchar>(x-1,y) != I.at<uchar>(x,y) || I.at<uchar>(x+1,y) != I.at<uchar>(x,y)||
           I.at<uchar>(x,y-1) != I.at<uchar>(x,y) || I.at<uchar>(x,y+1) != I.at<uchar>(x,y)){
            d.at<uchar>(x, y) = 0;
        }
    }
}
for(int y = 1; y < Y-1; y++){
    for(int x = 1; x < X-1; x++){
            if(d.at<uchar>(x-1,y-1)+d2<d.at<uchar>(x, y)){d.at<uchar>(x, y) = d.at<uchar>(x-1, y-1)+d2;}
            if(d.at<uchar>(x,y-1)+d1<d.at<uchar>(x, y)){d.at<uchar>(x, y) = d.at<uchar>(x, y-1)+d1;}
            if(d.at<uchar>(x+1, y-1)+d2<d.at<uchar>(x, y)){d.at<uchar>(x, y) = d.at<uchar>(x+1, y-1)+d2;}
            if(d.at<uchar>(x-1, y)+d1<d.at<uchar>(x, y)){d.at<uchar>(x, y) = d.at<uchar>(x-1, y)+d1;}
    }
}

for(int y = Y-1; y > 1; y--){
    for(int x = X-1; x > 1; x--){
        if(d.at<uchar>(x+1, y)+d1<d.at<uchar>(x, y)){d.at<uchar>(x, y) = d.at<uchar>(x+1, y)+d1;}
        if(d.at<uchar>(x-1, y+1)+d2<d.at<uchar>(x, y)){d.at<uchar>(x, y) = d.at<uchar>(x-1, y+1)+d2;}
        if(d.at<uchar>(x, y+1)+d1<d.at<uchar>(x, y)){d.at<uchar>(x, y) = d.at<uchar>(x, y+1)+d1;}
        if(d.at<uchar>(x+1, y+1)+d2<d.at<uchar>(x, y)){d.at<uchar>(x, y) = d.at<uchar>(x+1, y+1)+d2;}
    }
}
for(int y = Y-1; y > 1; y--){
    for(int x = X-1; x > 1; x--){
        if(I.at<uchar>(x,y)==0){d.at<uchar>(x, y)=-d.at<uchar>(x, y);}
    }
}
```

Compile, y me da resultados mas lógicos como figura en el documento que pasaste.

---

**EDIT:**
Para responder a tu comentario de una forma mas clara, te muestro este codigo refactorizado (que es tu 2do for)

```
for(int y = 1; y < Y-1; y++){
    for(int x = 1; x < X-1; x++){
            uchar& center = d.at<uchar>(x, y);

            // Checkeo pixel IZQUIERDA, ARRIBA
            uchar& leftTop = d.at<uchar>(x-1,y-1);
            if(leftTop+d2 < center) {
                center = leftTop + d2;
            }

            // Checkeo pixel ARRIBA
            uchar& top = d.at<uchar>(x,y-1);
            if(top + d1 < center) {
                center = top + d1;
            }

            // Checkeo pixel ARRIBA DERECHA
            uchar& rightTop = d.at<uchar>(x+1, y-1);
            if(rightTop + d2 < center) {
                center = rightTop + d2;
            }

            // Checkeo pixel IZQUIERDA
            uchar& left = d.at<uchar>(x-1, y);
            if(left + d1 < center) {
                center = left + d1;
            }
    }
}
```

Checkea, que las comprobaciones, se hacen sobre pixeles que ya iteraste.

### Ejemplo grafico de las iteraciones

> **Azul:** el pixel que estas iterando
>
> **Verde:** los pixeles que ya iteraste
>
> **C:** Los pixeles que estas consultando a la hora de iterar
>
> **Rojo:** Incidencia
>
> **Blanco:** Pixeles que aun no iteraste

Iteracion primero X y despues Y

[image: iteracion X y luego Y]

Iteración primero Y y despues X

[image: iteracion Y y luego X]

### Escribiendo fuera de los limites de la imagen

Hay otro problema, que lo tenes en todos los fors al usar x e y. De todas formas en el código de arriba esta reparado, pero de todas formas te lo remarco.

Analizando este código:

```
for(int i = 1; i < Y-1; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < X-1; j++){
        d.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
    }
}
```

Usas la variable **i** para x, pero iteras de **1 a Y (Height)**. Y lo mismo con la variable **j**. Por eso mismo, si la imagen no es del mismo ancho y alto, vas a estar escribiendo fuera de los limites de la imagen. Lo mas probable es que OpenCV este reportando un exception.

Espero que te sea de ayuda!

Comment: Gracias para este ejemplo es indiferente el recorrido por ser una matriz de n*n... Ya he echo más pruebas de estrés, y me han dado errores muy groseros del compilador, he cambiado el tamaño de las img. de entrada y para las mismas condiciones dan errores distintos o no hay errores, me alegra saber que no es un error mio del todo. No puedo estar más tiempo con este código solo me queda comprender como funciona el algoritmo y depurar errores para disminuir los errores en el futuro. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: No es indiferente. Checkea el segundo for.
Para comenzar, se hacen comprobaciones sobre la misma matriz y se asigna a la que se esta consultando.
Las comprobaciones son a los pixeles que ya recorriste, por lo que hacer primero Y despues X varia mucho su comportamiento.
Y eso mismo lo comprobe, se obtienen diferentes resultados.

Y segundo, el problema de memoria que tenes, es seguramente relacionado a lo mismo. Mira este codigo:
for(int i = 1; i < Y-1; i++){
donde i lo usas para el X, y recorres de 1 a Y.

Ahora modifico mi respuesta original para que quede mas completa.

Comment: Listo! Checkea lo que modifique en la respuesta, saludos.